# How to get promise.response to return an API’s response?

Tags: javascript, express, promise

TLDR: my promise.response needed to be called within both the API call and the promise.

I am attempting to get a return value from an API call via a Promise for a simple Express.js server.

This seems to be a topic of a lot of questions, but I have yet to successfully adapt an implementation to this case. I've also tried:

- placing the API call within resolve()
- async/wait implementations (willing to revisit)

Here's the basic structure of the code in question. There's a comment above the section where the trouble probably is.

### Promise

```
const externalModule = require('<route to module>');

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    // This is probably where the problem is
    let returnValue = externalModule.apiCall(parameters);
    resolve(returnValue);
});

promise.then(function(returnValue) {
    console.log(returnValue);
});
```

### External Module

```
module.exports = {
    apiCall: function(parameters) {
        apiCall(
            parameters,
            function(err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log("success");
                    return response
                }
            }
        )
    }
};
```

If the code were working properly, we'd see two strings. One from inside the API call ("success") and another from it's return value. Because undefined is appearing before "success," we know that the resolve function has fired before the function above it has returned.

### Logs from the Shell

```
> undefined
> "success"
```

Comment: You should make external module return a promise. `resolve()` doesn't magically await a return value

Comment: Your inner API call seems to be async and you ignore that. You have several options here, including passing `resolve` and `reject` to the `apiCall` and call both in corresponding clauses of the `if` or making the `apiCall` returning the promise itself. The major mistake here is your attempt to hide the async nature of the apiCall by wrapping it around yet another call that is synchronous to its caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't providing a way to use the response from the api call. Convert that toa promise and then use it.

```
module.exports = {
  apiCall: function(parameters) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      apiCall(
        parameters,
        function(err, response) {
          if (err) {
            rej(err);
          } else {
            res(response);
          }
        }
      )
    });
  }
};
```

Then use it like so

```
let promise = externalModule.apiCall(parameters);
```